# Does bin/bash access allow the user to find the server password?

Tags: ssh

I had a server that had a lot of users on it, its operating system was cloudlinux and had cpanel!

This server is used for Python projects and had bin/bash!!! access

Suddenly the command rm -rf * was typed on the server and all the data was deleted !!!

We quickly uploaded the backups and hacked the possibility and restricted ssh access to the root server!

But the next night we were hacked again, this time with the monitoring we had at whm! , we noticed that someone enters whm and quickly changes the password !!!

My question is whether users with access to bin/bash! can find the root password ???

We are now giving users access to JailShell in CPanel and full SSH access is closed. Do you have any idea how this happened?

Did you encounter a similar case?

Does bin/bash access allow the user to see the password?

Thank you for sharing your comments with us

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to obtain a Linux password, even with full access to the computer.  That's because the passwords are stored in hashed form.  Probably the only reliable way to get a password is to install a trick password change program, which does the change, but also sends the password somewhere else.

However, you don't need the password to get full access to a computer.  There are several other ways in, and anyone who can access `/bin/bash` is likely to be able to test them and probably find one that works.  Once they get full access, most intruders will install some other program that will let them in in the future, even if the original security hole is patched.

Once a machine is compromised, it's pretty important to burn it and start fresh.  You can't trust it otherwise.